# Crear un array de objetos a partir de otro array de objetos

Tags: javascript

estoy trabajando con arrays y tengo un inconveniente, necesito generar un array de objetos a  partir de otro array de objetos.

Tengo el siguiente array del que **quiero extraer únicamente el name** para generar el nuevo

```js
this.encabezado = [{
    name: 'FECHA DE CREACIÓN',
    htype: 2,
    value: '2022/05/10'
    property: 'fecha'
  }, 
  {
    name: 'PLAZO',
    htype: 2,
    value: 2
    property: 'plazo'
  },
  {
    name: 'FOLIO',
    htype: 1,
    value: '1200012'
    property: 'folio'
  },
  {
    name: 'EMPRESA',
    htype: 1,
     value: 'ejemplo sa de cv'
    property: 'empresa'
  }
  
];
```

el resultado debe ser de la siguiente manera:

```js
this.encabezadoNuevo = [{
    name1: 'FECHA DE CREACIÓN',
    name2: 'PLAZO',
    name3: 'FOLIO',
    name4: 'EMPRESA',
  }
];
```

Comment: Deberías agregar que has intentado hasta el momento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un ciclo "For of", te comparto un ejemplo.

Nota: "encabezado" -> es tu lista de objetos.

Al realizar cada iteración la variable "element" toma el valor de cada objeto de la lista y puedes acceder a sus propiedades por medio de la nomenclatura del punto "element.name" o "element.value" etc-

Podrías agregar al ciclo un colector que guarde esta información en un nuevo objeto.

Espero te sea de ayuda.

```
for(element of encabezado){
let nameHeader = element.name;
console.log(nameHeader);
```

}

```js
let encabezado = [{
    name: 'FECHA DE CREACIÓN',
    htype: 2,
    value: '2022/05/10',
    property: 'fecha'
  }, 
  {
    name: 'PLAZO',
    htype: 2,
    value: 2,
    property: 'plazo'
  },
  {
    name: 'FOLIO',
    htype: 1,
    value: '1200012',
    property: 'folio'
  },
  {
    name: 'EMPRESA',
    htype: 1,
     value: 'ejemplo sa de cv',
    property: 'empresa'
  }
  
];

for(element of encabezado){
    let nameHeader = element.name;
    console.log(nameHeader);

}
```

Comment: Como podría generar el nuevo objeto con los datos de la consola, de la siguiente forma.

this.encabezadoNuevo = [{
    name1: 'FECHA DE CREACIÓN',
    name2: 'PLAZO',
    name3: 'FOLIO',
    name4: 'EMPRESA',
  }
];

Comment: Antes de iniciar el "for" declara el nuevo objeto vacío "let newObjectList = [];", y en cada iteración del "for" puedes ir agregando cada elemento con el método push(), ejemplo: newObjectList .push({
  name1: element.name,
});      para hacer dinámico el "name1" podrías agregar un contador  concatenarle el "índex" de cada ciclo.

Answer (score 0):

teniendo tu array original declarado, declaras uno vacio y despues usas el metodo map() para recorrerlo

```
let nuevoEncabezado = encabezado.map(objeto => nuevoEncabezado.push(objeto.name));

console.log(nuevoEncabezado)
```

el metodo map() itera sobre cada elemento del array original, y te permite trabajar con el (pasar una de las propiedades del objeto iterado como por ej: "name", a otro array).

La variable "objeto" que ves dentro de la funcion map es la representacion del elemento iterado, y puedo usarlo para acceder a sus propiedades: En este ejemplo uso push para añadir la propiedad "name" al array nuevo.

Es solo una de las formas de hacerlo.